# A naive question on rational equivalence of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, flatness

Let $X$ be a projective scheme and $\pi:\mathcal{Z} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ a surjective morphism of finite type such that for any pair $t_0, t_1 \in \mathbb{P}^1$, the fibers $\mathcal{Z}_{t_0}$ and $\mathcal{Z}_{t_1}$ are rationally equivalent subschemes of $X$. Does this imply $\pi$ is flat? Note here that I am not apriori assuming the rational equivalence of the fibers are coming from $\pi$.

Comment: How, precisely, are you defining rational equivalence for closed subschemes?  Are you using only the cycles of top-dimensional irreducible components (with appropriate multiplicities coming from the length of the structure sheaf at each generic point)?  In that case, the answer is "no", because I can always add some embedded structure in just one fiber of $\pi$.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am assuming that every irreducible component of every fiber of $\pi$ is of the same dimension.

Comment: "I am assuming that every irreducible component of every fiber of $\pi$ is of the same dimension."  That does not address my concern.  Are you assuming that every associated point of every fiber is a generic point of the fiber?  Are you assuming that $\pi$ is projective?

Comment: @JasonStarr No to the first question and yes to the second.